# What is the minimum number of integers needed to guarantee a solution for the 3SUM problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

For a set of distinct integers that can take a value between 0 and 100, in order to guarantee that 2 numbers in the set add to 100 (where we can pick the same number twice), we need a minimum of 50 distinct integers.

My question is this: for a set of distinct integers ranging from 0 to 225, how many distinct integers are required to guarantee a solution if 3 numbers must add to 225?  The same number can be chosen multiple times (ie 75, 75, 75).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=75$ and $I=[0,3n]\cap\mathbb Z$. Note that the set $[n+1,3n]\cap\mathbb Z$ has $2n$ elements and the sum of any 3 elements (possibly with repetition) is at least $3n+3>3n$.

Conversely suppose $A\subseteq I$ such that no 3 elements sum to $3n$. We can't have $n\in A$ since $n+n+n=3n$. If $k\in[0,n-1]\cap\mathbb Z$ then $k+k+(3n-2k)=3n$, so $A$ can't contain $\{k,3n-2k\}$. Let
$$
  B=\{n\}\cup\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}\{k,3n-2k\}.
$$
Note that $|B|=2n+1$. Then
$$
  |A\cap B|=|A\cap\{n\}|+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|A\cap\{k,3n-2k\}|\leq n.
$$
Thus
$$
  |A|=|A\cap B|+|A\cap(I\setminus B)|\leq n+|I\setminus B|
    =2n.
$$
That is, $2n+1=151$ is the minimal number of elements required to have 3 elements summing to $3n=225$.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the notation.  What is the set $I$ in this case?  Also, what is denoted by "$[  ]$" brackets? Is this just an ordinary set like $\{n\}$ or something special? Also, am I right to assume that the pipes in "$|B|$" indicate absolute value, or is it something else in this case?  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @JohnV $I=\{0,1,2,\ldots,3n\}$ is the set of integers to be chosen from. $[a,b]$ denotes the set of numbers between $a$ and $b$, inclusive (normally this notation is used for real numbers, which is why I intersect with $\mathbb Z$). If $S$ is a set then $|S|$ denotes the number of elements in $S$.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  Thank you for clarifying and for your response.